# How to do a complex Groupyby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
      a    b   id
1    10    6    1
2     6   -3    1
3    -3   12    1  # id is 1, but needs a tie breaker
4    -2   12    1  # id is 1, but needs a tie breaker
5     4    8    2 
6    12   11    2  
7     3   -5    2
8     3   -5    2
```

How would make a new dataframe which first takes the `id` column and then gets everytime that the column `b` is over 10, and if there are multiple rows that meet this criterion, then do a tie breaker by selecting the row with the minimum value in column `a`:

```
      a    b   id
1    -3   12    1 
2    12   11    2
```

I have a dataframe with like 2,000,000 rows and about 10,000 `id` values, so a for-loop is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, if `df` is your original DataFrame:

```
df2 = df[df['b'] > 10]
out = df2.loc[df2.groupby('id')['a'].idxmin()]
```

and you should get:

```
    a   b  id
3  -3  12   1
6  12  11   2
```

Comment: I don't this would work because the `min` has to be applied to a specific column rather than all of the columns. If it were possible to select using `df.min('a')` then that would work.

Answer (score 1):

you could group based on id and apply a function that queries for b>10 and looks for minimum a. see below

```
def my_func(group):
    return df.ix[group.query('b>10')['a'].argmin(), ['a','b']]

print df.groupby(['id']).apply(my_func).reset_index()
```

this results in

```
  id   a   b
0   1  -3  12
1   2  12  11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 6, -3, -2, 4, 12, 3, 3], 
'b': [6, -3, 12, 12, 8, 11, -5, -5], 
'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

Write a function that filters the `DataFrame` based on your condition for `b` and then get the index where `a` is minimum with `idxmin`. We then apply this function to the grouped data.

```
>>> def get_rows(data):
    ...     return data.loc[data.loc[data['b'] > 10].a.idxmin()]

>>> data.groupby('id').apply(get_rows)
     a   b  id
id            
1   -3  12   1
2   12  11   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another solution:

```
data = {'a': [10,6,-3,-2,4,12,3,3], 'b': [6,-3,12,12,8,11,-5,-5], 'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
grouper = df[df.b > 10].groupby(df.id)
filtered = list()
for group, group_data in grouper:
    filtered.append(group_data.apply(min))
df_filtered = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(filtered)

# output
    a   b  id
0  -3  12   1
1  12  11   2
```

**NOTE**: Your index for the result will be [0, 1] in this case.